# what is the meaning of (char*)1?

Tags: c

What is the meaning of this?

```
ptr=(char *)1;
```

in c? I searched many times but I couldn't find the meaning of this.

I know the meaning of pointer, you don't have to explain.

Comment: `(char *) 1` is a *cast expression* - it's basically telling the compiler to treat the literal value `1` as a `char *` instead of an `int`.

Comment: @JohnBode I think you typed into the wrong box. The one for answers is further down.

Comment: @jainee  The meaning is unknown because nobody knows what is the sense of the address with value 1.:)

Comment: You did not find what a cast is? Very hard to belive!

Comment: sorry.. but i found what is the meaning of this.

Answer (score 2):

It converts the integer `1` to a pointer `char*`. Which means "at address 1, I expect to have a character". Please note that this is not guaranteed to work, it depends on the system. In case of memory misalignment, this would cause undefined behavior.

This particular code is most likely not meaningful on any system. On systems with virtual addresses (such as a PC), you probably can't access address 1 directly. On systems where it is possible, you never want to use `char*` but `uint8_t*`. For example, many small microcontroller systems have various byte-sized hardware registers at address 1.

Comment: If `uint8_t` exist, then certainly `int8_t`, `uint8_t`, `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char` all exist as 8-bit octets as either unsigned or 2's complement.  What is the advantage/difference then of `uint8_t*` over `char *` that supports "you never want to use `char*` ..."

Comment: @chux What I mean is that you never want to use `char` to access raw data, because it has implementation-defined signedness.

Comment: How can a `char` access cause cause memroy _alignment_ issues?

Comment: @chux Because it might be larger than one byte?

Comment: The `sizeof (char)` is _always_ 1.  The `sizeof uin8_t` cannot be smaller.